# How to positioning property panel in topleft of the autodesk forge viewer?

Tags: properties, panel, positioning, autodesk-forge

I want to positioning "property panel" in topleft of the autodesk forge viewer while loading itself with default main property.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of approaches to go here - adjust the specific styling below to your needs:

```
<style>
#ViewerPropertyPanel{top:0px!important;left:0px!important}
</style>
//or
<script>
viewer.getPropertyPanel(true).container.style.left=0
viewer.getPropertyPanel(true).container.style.top=0
</script>
```